# Log configuration lost when upgrading to Jetty 7

Tags: java, logging, jetty

We run our application using jetty:run (with maven). After upgrading to Jetty 7, we are no longer able to configure the log level. This causes everything on the DEBUG-level to be logged, which means that the logging become pretty useless since there are thousand of lines generated form the simplest server requests.

Is there any known problems when upgrading to Jetty 7, or something that have to be changed for this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In jetty 7, packages were renamed from org.mortbay.jetty to org.eclipse.jetty. This could be a problem if these are referred in configuration file.